# Selecting elements last css

Tags: css

I am building my stuff with semantic ui react, I think it is taking precedence over some of my other css. I am trying to set text to black after it is set to white by `<Menu ....... inverted>`.

Here's my code, Menu.Item lies in a Menu which has called "inverted" and will make everything inside that component the opposite color. Thus, I think a lot of the things I am trying are not working.

```
<Menu.Item>
      <Dropdown item text=<i class="user outline icon" /> direction="left">
        <Dropdown.Menu>
          {isAuthenticated ? (
            <div class="hiiii">
              <Dropdown.Item>
                <a id="hii" color="white">
                  Let's welcome {username}!
                </a>
              </Dropdown.Item>
              <a id="hii" color="white" onClick={this.travelToProfile}>
                <Dropdown.Item>Profile! (in development)</Dropdown.Item>
              </a>
              <a
                id="hii"
                color="black"
                onClick={this.travelToSavedRoadmaps}
              >
                <Dropdown.Item>
                  View saved roadmaps (in development)
                </Dropdown.Item>
              </a>

              <a id="hii" onClick={this.logOutClick}>
                <Dropdown.Item>Logout!</Dropdown.Item>
              </a>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <Dropdown.Item href="/login">
              <a id="hii">Please Log In</a>
            </Dropdown.Item>
          )}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    </Menu.Item>
```

I put a color attr after some `<a/>` just to test things out. After many testing, I figured some funny thing out: if I do

```
#hii {
  color: black;
}
```

The first a with id hii will turn black, the rest doesn't. Something that did work was `div {color: black !important}`, but that will turn the `<i class="user outline icon"/>` black too. So I am trying to only select those a tags and make them black. I had no luck with `a {color: black!important}`. Thanks, and sorry if I am not making sense, it's 2:46am damn!

Comment: You cannot have more than **one** element with any given `id` (such as `id="hii"`). `id` ***must be unique at all times***.

Comment: You might want to educate yourself about CSS `class`es.

Comment: replace all `id="hii"` with `className="color-dark"`. And define your class as `a.color-dark{color: black !important;}`. this should work. I believe this is a problem of css specificity https://specificity.keegan.st/.

Comment: Wow I really forgot the basics, sorry I was on auto pilot coding last night. Turns out that className="color-dark" and then setting the color doesn't work. I will look into the console for more info as why it doesn't work when I am done with the whole project. But for now, I just added a style={{color:"#FFFFFF"}} tag for the elements in the menu that I want to be white and left out the drop down menu which I wish to be black. Many Thanks